# JSON model texture not loading

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I've converted obj file to json model using python tool
and i'm trying to load it 
here is the code

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh, aircraft;

function addModelToScene( geometry, materials )
{
    aircraft = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
    scene.add( aircraft );
}

function init()
{
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 20000 );
    camera.position.z = 30;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
jsonLoader.load( "XA-20.js", addModelToScene );
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    aircraft.rotation.y += 0.02;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

model is loading but no textures on it 
model file is big so I can't post it here
but there are materials

```
"materials": [  {
"DbgColor" : 15658734,
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName" : "plane",
"colorAmbient" : [0.117647, 0.117647, 0.117647],
"colorDiffuse" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
"colorSpecular" : [0.75294099999999997, 0.75294099999999997, 0.75294099999999997],
"illumination" : 2,
"mapBump" : "XA-20_Razorback_Strike_Fighter_N.png",
"mapDiffuse" : "XA-20_Razorback_Strike_Fighter_P01.png",
"specularCoef" : 8.0
},

{
"DbgColor" : 15597568,
"DbgIndex" : 1,
"DbgName" : "glass",
"colorAmbient" : [0.117647, 0.117647, 0.117647],
"colorDiffuse" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
"colorSpecular" : [0.75294099999999997, 0.75294099999999997, 0.75294099999999997],
"illumination" : 2,
"mapDiffuse" : "Glass_Cockpit.png",
"specularCoef" : 8.0
},.......
```

and uvs as well

```
"uvs": [[0.72626,-0.65659,0.72655,-0.62558,0.72427,-0.6262,0.72391,-0.66141,0.73223,-0.62103,0.73212,.......
```

any clues where i can look for solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case problem was that I did not properly added lighting
so models didn't had enough light to appear as colorful
it did loaded textures but visually it was invisible because of lighting

so if run into similar problem check your lighting first

Answer (score 0):

jsonLoader.load has a third argument which sets the texturepath. Set this texturePath to the folder which has the textures and it should work.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js#L16

Comment: Hi I too ran into this problem. I am loading a model and if I use CanvasRenderer and I see the model complete with textures but when I use WebGLRenderer only a black model is displayed. Is there something else I am forgetting?